# Android 5 Restricted Account Allow Downloads

Tags: android, restricted-profiles

I have two new Samsung Tab A tablets, both running Android 5. I set both of them up at the same time and, as far as I know, the exact same way. I have a major problem with one of them:

How do I give permission to a Restricted Account user to download?

What is a "restricted account"? In settings, I went to Users and created a new Restricted Account under Users and Profiles. I then edited the account to give it permission to a bunch of apps installed on the device.

What does "download" mean? When I am in the owner account (the one that isn't restricted), I can use all of the apps. For example, I can play Goat Simulator. If I am in the restricted account, it says "Downloading file" and then fails immediately. Multiple apps do this. They try to download something and fail. If I run the app in the owner account, they download what they need and run just fine. Then, back to the restricted account, they try to download what I assume is the exact same file, but fail.

I've tried rebooting. I've done a factory reset. I've deleted and added the restricted account multiple times. It is always the same problem. The restricted account can't use at least half the apps because it apparently doesn't have permission to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I was inspecting the one that worked and the one that didn't and I finally found a difference - the one that doesn't work requires you to manually accept permissions to save files. To do so, go into settings, then apps, then select the app that isn't working. Select permissions. Chances are, it requires file permissions and that is grayed out. Click it to allow the permissions. Now, you must force stop the app. Then, you can start the app and, for the three apps I tried, they could suddenly work.

I have no idea why one tablet allowed file saving by default and the other requires the user to allow file saving manually per app.